# building a multidimention array php

Tags: php, arrays

I generate this array `$months` from an awstats file that looks like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 37
            [2] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 34
            [2] => 19
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 11
        )

)
```

Which `$months[0][0]` represent the number of a month and `$months[0][1]` it's data. What I'd like to do is to build an array that has all the number of months of the year  with it's data and if it doesn't have one make it to `0`.
Like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01
            [1] => 41
            [2] => 52
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02
            [1] => 74
            [2] => 66
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03
            [1] => 40
            [2] => 83
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 04
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 05
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 06
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )
```

and so on... Is there any way I can achieve this?Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried... anything?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea (if I understood your question right):

First, create another array ($sortedMonths) with 12 elements and fill them with 'empty data':

```
$sortedMonths = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $sortedMonths[] = array($i, 0, 0);
}

/*
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1,
                [1] => 0,
                [2] => 0
            )
        ...
        [11] => Array
            (
                [0] => 12,
                [1] => 0,
                [2] => 0
            )
    )
*/
```

Then loop through $months and assign data to the appropriate element of $sortedMonths:

```
foreach ($months as $month) {
    $sortedMonths[$month[0]-1] = $month;
}
```